# How to paste a copied row only once with excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make the following code work. The codes does find the first column that is empty but instead of pasting the selection once, it will paste the selection 6 times. I am not very familiar with macro's and can't figure out how to solve this.

```
Sheets("Fill in").Select
    Range("A2:H2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Waiting").Select
      Nr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Range("B" & Nr).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I tried to work around it by just removing the duplicates but will give errors half of the time.

```
 With Sheets("Waiting").Select
        Set Rng = Range("A2", Range("J999").End(xlDown))
        Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(5), Header:=xlNo
    End With
```

Comment: Are you trying to transpose the row to a column? `Transpose:= True` does that and the combination of that together with the `ActiveSheet.Paste` is causing some unwanted effects due to having the 8 rows (from the Transpose) selected and pasting the 8 values as columns (from your Fill in sheet's copy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're pasting a transposed set (vertically) then pasting again horizontally, filling what excel thinks is the range.

Try this

> Sheets("Fill in").Range("A2:H2").Copy
> Worksheets("Waiting").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

You don't need to copy and paste explicitly - you can just tell it the destination.

So in ONE line

WHAT to copy --> Sheets("Fill in").Range("A2:H2").Copy

DESTINATION  --> Worksheets("Waiting").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Comment: There's no need for `Copy` if there aren't numbers as texts to be copied, just `.Value` (with the orders reversed ofc) is enough.

Comment: You can also use an Array to handle this and avoid Copy/Paste.  VBA has an Application.Transpose(Array) function that will handle the transpose.